# Show Group Above Details Query

Tags: sql-server

Data in Table :

```
    ItemCode  ItemName     ItemGroup  
    SFD       Softdrink     NULL
    CCL       Coco Cola     SFD
    FNT       Fanta         SFD
    SPR       Sprite        SFD
    ACL       Alchol            
    TQL       Tequila       ACL
    VDK       Vodka         ACL
```

When user find "Softdrink" then the result will be:

```
    ItemCode       ItemName
    SFD            Softdrink     
    CCL            Coca Cola         
    FNT            Fanta                       
    SPR            Sprite
```

How could I do it?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
WITH hier (code, name) AS
        (
        SELECT  ItemCode, ItemName
        FROM    Table
        WHERE   ItemCode = 'SFD'
        UNION ALL
        SELECT  ItemCode, ItemName
        FROM    hier
        JOIN    Table
        ON      ItemGroup = code
        )
SELECT  *
FROM    hier
```

This will select items even with deeper hierarchy level (i. e. you can add `Fanta Lemon` and `Fanta Orange` with `ItemGroup = FNT`, and this query will select them too).

Answer (score 0):

All softdrinks are in itemgroup sfd. Try `select itemcode, itemname from table where itemgroup = 'SFD'`;

Mark Hamilton points out:

> Except Softdrink itself doesn't have SFD as its ItemGroup. You'd need to add "or ItemCode = 'SFD'" to your query. I wonder whether the categories can nest further, in which case a recursive CTE would do the trick

Yeah, either add an 'or' to the where, or go recursive.

Comment: Except Softdrink itself doesn't have SFD as its ItemGroup. You'd need to add "or ItemCode = 'SFD'" to your query. I wonder whether the categories can nest further, in which case a recursive CTE would do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

Got it Worked with

```
select ItemCode, ItemName from Items 
where itemCode in (select itemcode  from Items where itemname = 'softDrink') 
or itemGroup in  (select itemcode  from Items where itemname = 'softDrink')
```

Can this been modified further.